# Protege 5 JRELoaderError on macOS Sierra

Tags: java, protege

I had protege on Sierra before but for some reasons I reinstall my os. Now, when I try to open the protege I will get this message: `JRELoaderError`. I have java version 8 update 112

> java version "1.8.0_112"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?